# Quickly Access Safari 6 Bookmark & History Address Bar Suggestions with the Keyboard?

Tags: safari, macos, bookmarks

With the new combined address/search bar in Safari 6, I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly choose an option from the *Bookmarks & History* suggestions using the keyboard. Or some way to have bookmarks titles match as *Top Hits* the way URLs seem to.

In old versions you could quickly access a bookmark by typing the first few letters of it's name, hitting down and enter. But in Safari 6, you have to skip over 5 Google suggestions first, or just click with the mouse, neither of which is terribly efficient.

I suspect this is a quixotic request, but I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a real solution, but a little faster then pure <kbd>down</kbd>.
You can jump over the different sections with <kbd>command-down</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, that's close enough. I tried some different key combinations, but somehow I guess I missed that one. Go figure. Still not happy with the pattern matching decisions Apple made, but this is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the suggested keywords by checking "Prevent search engine from providing suggestions" in the privacy preferences. There will still be a single action for searching for the text on the location bar, but that's actually useful in a lot of cases.

[image]

And if you're used to searching in history and bookmarks, it's much better than this:

[image]