# Bookmarks in Safari: Type bookmark name to go to it

Tags: keyboard, safari, bookmarks

I have a bunch of bookmarks named things like "CNC" "FB" and "HQ" and the like.

I'm a bit of a keyboard junkie. I want to be able to access these quickly, by typing CMD-L, and then such initials into Safari's address bar.

Sometimes it works, the initials make it into the Top Hits
[image: when it works] 
This allows me to down cursor and press return.

But, most of the time the google search comes up first. That's so much pressing I might as well have just used the pointer.

I saw [Quickly Access Safari 6 Bookmark & History Address Bar Suggestions with the Keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59545/quickly-access-safari-6-bookmark-history-address-bar-suggestions-with-the-keyb) but I don't want to disable the suggested search, just down prioritize it under my bookmarks, which surely should be a better hit than random stuff on the internet.

So, in a nutshell - can I customize Safari to have have "Bookmarks and History" to appear as the first (top result) section to replace Top Hits?

Comment: Another way of thinking about this is that I want "Bookmarks and History" to appear as the first section, in Top Hits.

Comment: And I noted cmd-down. Still not what I wanted.

Comment: Also wondering this but I'd like bookmarks and history to be discrete sections.